# Where is Backbone.Model.extend method defined?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm reading Backbone.js code and can't find the definition of `Backbone.Model.extend` method.

Where is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the source, under [Helpers](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-247), there's a *helper function to correctly set up the prototype chain, for subclasses* :

```
var extend = function(protoProps, staticProps) {

}
```

which is then assigned to all Backbone prototypes

```
Model.extend = Collection.extend = Router.extend = View.extend = extend;
```

Comment: Is it all right to add extend method directly inside Model.prototype? 
In this place,
<pre>
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(){/*some codes */}
_.extend(Model.prototype, Events, {
  extend: extend
  /*other code*/
}
</pre>

Comment: @soarinblue That depends what you want to achieve, using `_.extend` on the prototype would set the function as an instance method, not as a static property as in Backbone source, and that may or may not be what you want.